# How to remove node to agroup to the same level in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am trying group all records to the same level (I agree that it is not correct, but the legacy system already working in production environment).

I have this xml file...

[image]

Now, I need remove the nodes "SalesOrg" keeping the values... the file need get this structure.

[image]

I am using this XSLT to try it

[image]

But, the output XML file continue the same..

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to remove SalesOrg-Nodes use the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="SalesOrg">
    <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="SalesOrg">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied to the provided XML document (unable to copy/paste the picture!!!), produces the wanted result (unable to copy/paste the picture!!!).**